# .htaccess in multiple query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i try use .htaccess to make clean URL. But i have problem in mutiple query string parameters.

I have three kinds of URL format like this :

```
 1. http://localhost/websekolah/main.php?page=register
 2. http://localhost/websekolah/main.php?page=detail_news&uid=10
 3. http://localhost/websekolah/main.php?page=gallery&hal=3
```

And i want my URL like this :

```
.    1. http://localhost/websekolah/register
     2. http://localhost/websekolah/detail_news/10
     3. http://localhost/websekolah/gallery/hal/3
```

I create this .htaccess but just only work for 1 query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[css|images|js|config|lib|pages] - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I check my url redirection using this in main.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];

        $_SESSION['curr_page'] = $page;

        if(isset($_GET['process'])) {

            $process = $_GET['process'];

            if(file_exists("pages/process_$process.php")) {
                include "pages/process_$process.php";
            } else {
                include "pages/404.php";
            }

        } else {
            if(file_exists("pages/body_$page.php")) {
                include "pages/body_$page.php";
            } else {
                include "pages/404.php";
            }
        }

    } else {
        include "pages/body_home.php";
    }
?>
```

Please help, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ main.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ main.php?page=$1&uid=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ main.php?page=$1&$2=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ main.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I also changed the *s into +s

Comment: These rules definitely need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` conditions.

Comment: @anubhava I don't think so. In the question there already is `RewriteRule ^[css|images|js|config|lib|pages] - [L,NC]` which suggests that the OP doesn't want any other files than in those directories to be directly accessible

Comment: All I can humbly suggest is to test your rules. You will be surprised to see results yourself.

Comment: @fanjavaid please hit me over the head. I forgot to put capturing brackets `()` around `[^/]+`. See my edited answer, I tested it and it works now

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

To

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php [L,QSA]

The query parameters will still be in `$_GET`

Comment: @fanjavaid well, my answer will still work. `main.php` will get executed for *all* requests that are not `css|images|js....`. You then have to look write PHP code to handle the routing yourself.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini no it won't. If you go to http://localhost/websekolah/register, the `page` parameter won't be set.

Comment: @Jonan ah you are correct. I do routing in PHP and send everything to a main pHP file. From there I have a routing table.

Comment: I already try your answer but it access homepage, when i access `http://localhost/websekolah/register`